# What does this import code in solidity actually do? Where are the files located?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, compilation

If MyCo.sol contract needs to access the Owned.sol contract, how is the file firing? Does the Owned.sol file have to be added to the blockchain prior to firing MyCo.sol; if so, does it just need to be set under the owners contract/address prior to executing ?
 Does the `./` or `../` location reference some location on the chain or only used to locate the file prior to setting it with a tx?

```
MyCo.sol    

import "../lib/Owned.sol";
```

how does MyCo.sol know where to find the imported files?  Have they become embedded somehow in the initial migration?
 I think I am just confused about the blockchain file structure and how it would access these imported files.  Is it all resident on the chain, or a hybrid between the MyCo.sol, the native go-ethereum language, and wbd3.js protocols?

Answer (score 2):

It's a compiler directive that tells it to load the file from the *compile-time local file system*. It's not relevant to anyone who uses the compiled contract other than verifying the bytecode against source; they will need to see it.

Although there are emerging de facto standards for such things, there is no assurance that your particular `Owned.sol` exactly matches anyone else's. Consequently, the actual source you are using for `Owned.sol` is part of your project and should be published with the rest of your code in the case that you want to publicize your source code.

`import` is roughly equal to including in the same source file, with the obvious advantage of avoiding code duplication:

```
contract Owned {
  // do something
}

contract Mine is Owned {
  // do something
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: That helped a lot, thank you. If I wanted not to duplicate code in my contract, could i point the import command to a contract hash instead of a defacto standard? for example: The import would be: import "../txid" , or could I point it to a myname.eth resolved name and point it to a contract on the chain; which in turn would call the contract from the chain and import it to mMyCo.sol?  or is my thinking skewed?

Comment: You can only point at source you have, not a deployed contract. But, Solidity has a different facility called Libraries that refer to published contracts you can use to avoid repetition.